# JSonNet boolean serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Quick question:

In JSONNet - how do i get bool true/false to serialize as bool 1/0

I can see how we handle null values and all that just cant seem to find how to do this.

is this possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can implement a custom converter like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class CustomJsonSerialization
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        string serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(true, new BoolConverter());
        Assert.That(serializeObject, Is.EqualTo("1"));
        var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(serializeObject, new BoolConverter());
        Assert.That(deserializeObject, Is.True);
    }
}

public class BoolConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((bool)value) ? 1 : 0);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return reader.Value.ToString() == "1";
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(bool);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi It only handles if my value is "1" what if I pass 2 instead of 1, It'll also get converted to false

Comment: Just code whatever logic you want. The sample code should make it pretty obvious how to do what you're asking.

Comment: I've to return a model state error in case user passes two. How to handle that

Comment: You should ask a new question rather than posting comments.

Comment: Hi David, I would have asked if I wouldn't have got your answer. But It's just about having one more addition to your answer. I thought you could probably help better and Reduce duplications

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by [this response in similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/85468/878327) it can be solved like the following.

```
[JsonIgnore]
public bool SomeFlag { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(nameof(SomeFlag))]
public int SomeFlagAsInt
{
    get => SomeFlag ? 1 : 0;
    set => SomeFlag = value > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@DavidPeden answer v2

### **Better string handling**

```
/// <summary>
///  CUSTOM BOOLEAN -> 0 | 1 CONVERTER
/// </summary>
public class BoolConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(bool.TryParse(value?.ToString(), out var parsed) ? (parsed ? 1 : 0) : 0);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return int.TryParse(reader.Value?.ToString(), out var parsed) && parsed == 1;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(bool) || objectType == typeof(bool?);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version (in vb) if anyone needs it. It also handles nullable Boolean

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class MyBooleanConverter
    Inherits JsonConverter

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CanWrite As Boolean
    Get
        Return True
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
    Dim boolVal As Boolean = value
    writer.WriteValue(If(boolVal, 1, 0))
End Sub

Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
    Dim value = reader.Value
    If IsNothing(value) OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()) OrElse "0" = value Then
        Return False
    End If
    If 0 = String.Compare("yes", value, True) OrElse 0 = String.Compare("true", value, True) Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function

Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
    Return objectType = GetType(Boolean) OrElse objectType = GetType(Boolean?) 'OrElse objectType = GetType(String)
End Function
End Class
```

I started this based on @John here: [how to get newtonsoft to deserialize yes and no to boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524669/how-to-get-newtonsoft-to-deserialize-yes-and-no-to-boolean/41838991#41838991)

Answer (score 0):

Declare two separate properties, hide the real one from serialization, and use the "fake" int one instead. Decorate both with Newton's attributes like this:

```
[JsonIgnore] public bool Bool { internal get; set; }
[JsonProperty("your_dispay_name")] public string Int { get { return this.Bool ? 1 : 0; } }
```