# How to Serialise/Deserialise when web service sends a bool but receives an int

Tags: c#, json

Currently working with the most annoying web service! I'm using Newtonsoft Json.Net.

When I request data, a bool property `EndOfDay` is sent as `true` or `false` - deserialize works fine BUT annoyingly, when I send data to the web service, for this same field I have to send either a 0 or 1 - don't ask why as I couldn't give you a good answer - All I know is I can't change it.

Is there a way of serializing bools to 0 or 1 even though when I deserialize the strings will be true/false or should I admit defeat and have separate objects which are almost identical except for this one property - one object has a bool and the other an int?

Comment: Can't you just use an `int` for serialization/deserialization in that field?

Comment: As far as i'm aware, Json.Net won't deserialize a bool to an int - it comes from the web service as a bool.

Comment: Then i don't understand why you should serialize as int. Anyway, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9738324/579895)

Comment: when I get from the web service I receive a bool BUT when I push to web service I have to provide a 0 or 1

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've looked at similar questions but they don't quite do what I need it to do.

Comment: Are you specifying the classes when deserializing? Maybe using a custom class to deserialize with that field as an int would solve the problem...

Comment: Yes I could do that as a last resort - I'm trying to avoid duplicating the class with one property difference though (if possible)

Comment: But that way you wouldn't duplicate anything, you would be just using that field always as an int. Anyway I'm not sure if it would work or would Json.Net complaint about that ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to use custom conveter:

```
class Test {
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StrangeBoolConverter))]
    public bool EndOfDay { get; set; }

    private class StrangeBoolConverter : JsonConverter {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
            // write it as 1 or 0
            writer.WriteValue((bool) value ? 1 : 0);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
            // but when reading - expect "true" or "false"
            return Convert.ToBoolean(reader.Value);
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
            return objectType == typeof(bool);
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>("{\"EndOfDay\":\"true\"}");
var back = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test); // {"EndOfDay": "1"}
```

Comment: Well..isn't that more or less the answer of the question i linked in the comments? :)

Comment: @Pikoh well indeed, but I didn't see your comment and that answer before you now told me :)

Comment: It's ok,I think it's probably the best answer

Comment: Ah - this example is actually a lot easier for me to understand than the linked one in the comments. Let me give it a shot.

Comment: @Rick well he did tailor it exactly to your application, so that helps.  Good answer

Comment: cool - all working as I require. Thanks for the help guys. I didn't realise I could change the example to work differently in each "direction".