# Newtonsoft - deserialize “1” as conditional bool property

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonserializer

I have the following JSON object:

```
  {
    "entity": "Customer",
    "id": "XXX",
    "isActive": "1",
    "createdTime": "2018-01-30T18:56:51+02:00",
    "updatedTime": "2019-01-05T02:15:17+02:00",
```

and the following DTO class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedTime { get; set; }
}
```

and code for deserialization:

```
        var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(customerString);
        JToken array = jsonResponse["response_data"];
        List<Customer> result = (List<Customer>)array.ToObject(typeof(List<Customer>));
```

but I have a problem with `IsActive` property, because json object has 1 or 0 values, but I want to have boolean. How to write JsonSerializer to do it?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Convert an int to bool with Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14427596) or [JSonNet boolean serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9738324).  Agree?

Comment: you are right, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very nice code from Pete at [how to get newtonsoft to deserialize yes and no to boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524669/how-to-get-newtonsoft-to-deserialize-yes-and-no-to-boolean)

```
public class JsonBooleanConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var value = reader.Value.ToString().ToLower().Trim();
    switch (value)
    {
        case "true":
        case "yes":
        case "y":
        case "1":
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
    if (objectType == typeof(Boolean))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Usage:

```
var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, new JsonBooleanConverter())
```