# How do I get Newtonsoft to serialize a bool as false, not False or "false"

Tags: c#, json.net

If I serialize a bool value I get something like this:

```
myboolValue: False
```

I realize that this is due to Microsoft's `ToString()` implementation of bools.

Is there a setting that I can change in Newtonsoft to output false like:

```
myboolValue: false
```

I can switch to string with a `conditional ? "true" : "false"`, but that adds quotes in the JSON like:

```
myboolValue: "false"
```

Can a custom serializer remove the quotes?

Comment: Why are you storing booleans as strings to begin with? What's wrong with a `bool`?

Comment: Have you looked at implementing a custom converter? [JSonNet boolean serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738324/jsonnet-boolean-serialization)

Comment: @RufusL I don't think a custom converter is needed here, the desired behavior is the default behavior for boolean types in JSON.NET.

Comment: see https://dotnetfiddle.net/fNLCAP - looks fine to me

Comment: @SirRufo Yes, that does look right. Either .NET Core is behaving differently, or we are messing something else up on our end. Frontear: We are using bool, we only switch to string in my 3rd example to try to work around. Looks like I have more investigation to do. Sorry for the bad question.

Comment: @MVinca - Json.NET serializes `bool` as specified by the [JSON standard](https://json.org/) on .Net core as well as .Net full framework.  Possibly your framework has a custom `JsonConverter` that is messing things up?  Try adding `[JsonConverter(typeof(NoConverter))]` to your Boolean property where `NoConverter` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39739105/3744182), it will suppress any global converter.  But beyond that I think we need a [mcve].

Answer (score 11):

Newtonsoft.Json serializes bool as true/false out of the box:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Test
{
    public bool f1;
    public bool f2;

    public Test()
    {
        f1 = false;
        f2 = true;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Test());
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Outputs to console:

```
{"f1":false,"f2":true}
```

Additionally you can use improved JSON bool converter which writes C# bool as true/false and able to read bool from true/false/yes/no/1/0 string values of any upper/lower case:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles converting JSON string values into a C# boolean data type.
/// </summary>
public class BooleanJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    #region Overrides of JsonConverter

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this instance can convert the specified object type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// <c>true</c> if this instance can convert the specified object type; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool CanConvert( Type objectType )
    {
        // Handle only boolean types.
        return objectType == typeof(bool);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the JSON representation of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader">The <see cref="T:Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader"/> to read from.</param>
    /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
    /// <param name="existingValue">The existing value of object being read.</param>
    /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The object value.
    /// </returns>
    public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        switch (reader.Value.ToString().ToLower().Trim())
        {
            case "true":
            case "yes":
            case "y":
            case "1":
                return true;
            case "false":
            case "no":
            case "n":
            case "0":
                return false;
        }

        // If we reach here, we're pretty much going to throw an error so let's let Json.NET throw it's pretty-fied error message.
        return new JsonSerializer().Deserialize( reader, objectType );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the JSON representation of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The <see cref="T:Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter"/> to write to.</param><param name="value">The value.</param><param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
    public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        writer.WriteValue((bool)value);
    }

    #endregion Overrides of JsonConverter
}
```

To register this converter use the code:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
    {
        new BooleanJsonConverter()
    }
};
```

Comment: @chrnoxor We can also add nullables `bool?` to this code by changing this: 
`return objectType == typeof(bool) || objectType == typeof(bool?);` 

and using null propagation here: 
`switch (reader.Value?.ToString()?.ToLower()?.Trim())` so if `reader.Value` is null it won't break when bool?, only for bool