# c# How to convert string to bool with ObjectSerializer

Tags: c#

I am trying to fetch data from my server.
It is returned as JSON:

```
item    {{   "name": "Event1",   "tblEventID": "1",   "timeCreated": "2021-08-03 11:47:16",   "timeUpdated": "2021-08-05 15:08:19",   "userID": "6",   "description": "Ein ganz toller Event",   "venueName": "TollesVenue",   "venueAdresse": "VenueStraße in Straßburg",   …}
```

I tried serializing object like so:

```
 public static List<EventType> Deserialize(ApiResponse response)
    {
        List<EventType> ad = new List<EventType>();

        var array = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)response.payload;
        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            EventType x = (EventType)(item.ToObject(typeof(EventType)));
            ad.Add(x);

        }
        return ad;
    }
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Could not convert string to boolean: 1. Path 'payload[0].displayStartTime'.
```

So it is failing while trying to convert the string "1" into my eventType where "displayStartTime" is ofc a bool.

Now I can make my type a string and it works fine, but thats not the point. I want to keep it as bool in my model.

However, Since I am basically using one line of code:

```
EventType x = (EventType)(item.ToObject(typeof(EventType)));
```

To make the conversion, I cannot access the single steps and intercept the bool / string missmatch.

How could I parse the object, keeping the bool in the model and deserializing the whole json?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using a custom converter like desribed here:

[How do I get Newtonsoft to serialize a bool as false, not False or "false"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152416/how-do-i-get-newtonsoft-to-serialize-a-bool-as-false-not-false-or-false)

Basically I overwrote the JasonReader:

```
 public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        switch (reader.Value.ToString().ToLower().Trim())
        {
            case "true":
            case "yes":
            case "y":
            case "1":
                return true;
            case "false":
            case "no":
            case "n":
            case "0":
                return false;
        }
```

Comment: Why was it trying to map a field named `DisplayStartTime` as a boolean in the first place?

Comment: Because of my model i define displayStartTime as a bool. :)

Comment: I get it now... it's "yes, display the start time", or "no, don't display the start time". It looked at first to me like a field for the timestamp when display started.

Comment: right it is a yes or no question: "Display the starting time?" And not a request: "Display the starting time". ;)

Comment: FYI - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234591/upper-vs-lower-case and maybe trim before calling tolower/toupper