# How to handle both 0/1 and false/true values for booleans in requestbody

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-binding, api-design

I'm currently migrating functionalities from an old HTTP API to a new HTTP API.
Several endpoints of the api expect objects with nullable boolean values as a JSON object in the requestbody.

Modelcode:

```
public class StatusRequest
{
    public bool? Status {get; set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost, Route("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RequestStatus([FromBody] StatusRequest requestData )
{
    if(requestData.Status)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    else
    { 
        return BadRequest(); 
    }
}
```

My problem is now that since I'm migrating from an old API that used 0/1 integers as boolean values and we want the neccessary changes on the userside to be as minimal as possible, the API should be able to read both 0/1 and false/true for the properties in the requestbody.

First I tried to implement a custom model binding class implementing IModelBinder, that handles the 0/1 and the nullable values but the binding was ignored due to the [FromBody] attribute. I can't remove the [FromBody] attribute though, because then our swagger documentation displays the requestmodel as individual parameters and not as a single requestbody. I also can't add examples of requestbodies to the documentation because the OpenApiOperation class doesn't have a RequestBody property anymore.

Is there a way I can handle my nullable and integer values and still have a correct documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to declare a `JsonConverter`. make sure that your API is using `NewtonsoftJson` for handling api json serialization/deserialization. then you should create a custom JsonConverter which derives from `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter` and handles boolean fields.

Then you need to add the convertor that you made to newtonsoftJson `SerializerSettings` in your `Program.cs` like so:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new BoolJsonConverter());
    });
```

If you want to know how you can declare a `BoolJsonConverter` you can take a look at [How do I get Newtonsoft to serialize a bool as false, not False or "false"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152416/how-do-i-get-newtonsoft-to-serialize-a-bool-as-false-not-false-or-false).

Let us know if it could help you solve your problem.

Comment: As I'm using .net 7 [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0) should work aswell shouldn't it? I used the System.Text.Json Library in the whole project and am a bit reluctant to change that.

Comment: Yes, System.Text.Json Also supports Custom JSON converters; although, I couldn't find a code example to applying the configuration in MVC JSON Configuration. but it should be fairly similar to the newtonsoft Configuration.

Comment: I just noticed this doesn't seem to work as I want it to. I can create a JsonConverter for type bool? but that will only execute on properties that are already boolean values. The integer values of 0 and 1 will be ignored completely. I also can't just implement a global integer converter as I have other integer values that can be 0 or 1 without representing a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is creating multiple DTOs as [body] inputs on the same endpoint, like so

```
public class StatusRequest1
{
    public bool Status {get; set;}
}

public class StatusRequest2
{
    public int Status {get; set;}
}
```

And your controller would be like this:

```
[HttpPost, Route("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RequestStatus([FromBody] StatusRequest1 requestData )
{
    ...   
}

[HttpPost, Route("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RequestStatus([FromBody] StatusRequest2 requestData )
{
    ...
}
```

After that you can parse the `int` value back to `bool`. and the API client can call this endpoint with both int and bool values.

BUT if your only concern is the `1/0` and `true/false` values and not the data Types, you can declare it as `public string Status {get; set;}` and parse its value to `bool` inside your model.