# Make Json.Net serialize booleans as strings

Tags: c#, json.net

I would like to force Newtonsoft.Json's `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` to always threat bool values as strings: `"true"` and `"false"`.

I know that `JsonConvert` is a static class, and I should probably write an extension method something like this one:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings {}
```

but to be honest I have no idea how to do it nor how to implement it into my method:

```
public static string Serialize(Foo fooData)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fooData);
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: This quite similar question could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738324/jsonnet-boolean-serialization

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a simple [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to do this:

```
public class BoolToStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(bool);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue((bool)value ? "true" : "false");
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new BoolToStringConverter() },
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aEO1hG

Comment: Thank you so much for both resolving my problem and spelling correction :)