# Json.net : Do not derserialize numbers as booleans

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

Is there any built in settings in json.net to disable the  conversion of numbers to booleans. I would prefer it to return an error instead : (without writing a Custom Converter for each class that has a bool property )

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public bool flag { get; set; }
    }

    var str = @"{"flag":123}";
    MyClass result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(str) ; // flag is true !
```

Comment: A serializer would not serialize a bool to `123`...well, not a well working one

Comment: yes, but what if the data is entered manually by a user

Comment: You don't need a custom converter for each class.

Comment: You'll need to sanitize this data yourself first.  A `bool` in this context is clearly defined by JSON.NET as non-zero being `true` and zero being `false`.  Your software should not allow the entry of a number that you don't want.

Comment: Only allow the user to enter `true/false`. Don't allow them to enter `123` in a boolean field

Comment: or zero and one.

Comment: You could never store `"I like pie"` or any non bool in a boolean field in a class in order to be serialized, so this appears to be an XY problem

Comment: [Json.net Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) can validate your json

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp of course you can , if you are using a dynamic language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use different types in one property to get one `bool` result.
But if you wish not to declare one custom JsonConvert for every property in the class, you can always create DefaultSettings in your code.

```
void Initialize()
{
    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
        {
            new BoolJsonConverter()
        }
    };
}

// Create JsonConvert you want to add to DefaultSettings
public class BoolJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(bool);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {

    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {

    }
}

var json = @"{""flag"":123}"
var myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

Comment: Complete code is available in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9741557/477420

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a Deserialize only situation. If that is the case, you could have your `int` value go into an `int` and use another var to hold the `bool`. Something like -

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int flagInt { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool flag
    {
        get
        {
            switch (flagInt)
            {
                case 0: return false;
                case 1: return true;
                default: throw new Exception("Cannot convert flag to bool");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I don't have a setter on `flag` so doing something like `flag = false` will not have expected results and will not serialize correctly either.

Comment: good trick, but it needs to be implemented on every boolean property of every class of the application