# Convert true and false to 1 and 0 in XmlElement in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xsd, xmlserializer

I am working with a SOAP web service from a third party.  I have generated objects using the `XSD.exe` tool.  The problem is that I need to send an `XmlElement` that I'm serialising.  Their service is throwing an error because it expects all `boolean` values to be represented by 1 and 0 instead of true and false.

I know I can use a custom serializers such as this: [IXmlSerializable Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) or this: [Making the XmlSerializer output alternate values for simple types](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingTheXmlSerializerOutputAlternateValuesForSimpleTypes.aspx) but they involve me changing the code generated by the `Xsd.exe` tool and would be difficult to maintain every time there was an upgrade.

Am I missing something or is there a another way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Can't you skip serializing the `bool` property, and define a computed public `int` property returning `BoolProp ? 1 : 0` instead?

Comment: Please attach sample code?

Comment: The service has hundreds of complex types and many contain bools so I'm looking for something that I don't need to do on a property by property basis.

Comment: Using an approach as @dasblinkenlight suggested together with [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) could get you the desired result. I don't think there is an addin which does such a transformation so you would have to create one yourself. The benefit of such a solution would be that the special handling of `bool` values would be transparent for the rest of your application.

Comment: I don't think so.  Identical questions were never answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722407) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763679).  Even if you subclass `XmlWriter` and override `WriteValue(bool value)` it doesn't help, since `XmlSerializer` calls `WriteRaw(string value)` with the strings `"true"` or `"false"` directly instead.  Could you serialize to an intermediate `XDocument` and postprocess it?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your object ignore the bool value but instead use a different Variable to show it. As example:

```
    [IgnoreDataMember, XmlIgnore]
    public bool BoolProp  { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     XML serialized BoolProp 
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "BoolProp"]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "BoolProp"]
    public int FormattedBoolProp 
    {
        get { 
            return BoolProp ? 1 : 0;
        }
        set { BoolProp = value==1 }
    }
```

This will make the XML parser ignore the real property, but instead use the formatted function.

You could remove the setter if you do not need to parse it.